# Error while conditionally using perl module

Tags: perl

```
if (a == b)
{
    eval "require IO::Compress::Gzip qw(gzip)";
}
```

This is what I did to include gzip based on a condition, but at run time it gives error as below

```
Can't locate object method "gzip" via package "IO::Handle" (perhaps you forgot to load "IO::Handle"?)
```

Any help please? thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To conditionally include a module, use the [`if`](http://perldoc.perl.org/if.html) pragma

```
use if ($x == $y), 'IO::Compress::Gzip' => qw(gzip);
```

Just note that the variables in the CONDITION will have to be package level and initialized in a BEGIN block.

Alternatively, you can use the following:

```
if ($x == $y) {
    require IO::Compress::Gzip;
    IO::Compress::Gzip->import('gzip');
}
```

Comment: Miller, I used your second solution, got the same error, let me try "use". I am using perl, v5.6.1 Thanks.

Comment: Does doing a basic use statement give that error?  `use IO::Compress::Gzip qw(gzip);`  I suspect that there is something else going on with your environment.

Comment: yes, use IO::Compress::Gzip qw(gzip $GzipError); works, but not your alternative solution, may be Perl version 5.6.1 don't have that support?

Comment: Perl 5.6.1 is more than 13 years old. But I don't think that's related to your error.

Comment: Perl 5.6.1 isn't even the latest Perl 5.6.x release!

Comment: Yes, I am stuck with it for some time, thanks for your answer, I am pushing to move to latest Perl :)